# Why aspectRatio has no effect?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Text("Hi!")
            .font(.title)
    }
    .aspectRatio(16/9, contentMode: .fit)
    .background(.yellow)
}
```

I expected the ZStack to resize and adjust aspectRatio but it has no effect and I am getting the following

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ZStack is always exactly the size of its contents (in this case, Modifier View that contains a Text). A Text is always exactly the size of the text it contains. Since nothing here has a flexible size, `aspectRatio` isn't going to do anything.

`Color` has a flexible size, so if you add it to the ZStack, it will make the ZStack also flexible, allowing an aspect ratio to be applied:

```
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear  // A flexible-sized View within the ZStack
            Text("Hi!")
                .font(.title)
        }
        .aspectRatio(16/9, contentMode: .fit)
        .background(.yellow)
    }
```

I assume this is what you're looking for.

[image: Simulator image with 16:9 yellow highlight around Text]